# Filter an object containing multiple lists on a common field c#

Tags: linq, list, c#-4.0

I am trying to find if there is some quick way to filter an object that has multiple list elements on a common field. Example, if I have vital height and weight lists in vital class, I want to filter the vital object to return the data in the list filtered by `EntryDate`.

```
public class VitalHeight
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string EnterDate { get; set; }
}

public class VitalWeight
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string EnterDate { get; set; }
}

public class Vital
{
  public double PaientId { get; set; }
  public List<VitalWeight> Weights { get; set; }
  public List<VitalHeight> Heights { get; set; }
}

Vital vitals = controller.GetAllVitals(1234); // Get vitals by patient id
```

Is there an easy way to filter the vitals that I got from `GetAllVitals()` by `EntryDate`?

I have data in `vitals` object something like:

```
PatientId: 1234
Weights: {[Id: 1, Value: 290, EntryDate: 1/31/2017 12:34:00 PM], 
          [Id: 2, Value: 291, EntryDate: 1/31/2017 2:14:00 PM]}
Heights: {[Id: 1, Value: 5.7, EntryDate: 1/31/2017 12:34:00 PM]}
```

So, the output for `EntryDate="1/31/2017 12:34:00 PM"` should be:

```
PatientId: 1234
Weights: {[Id: 1, Value: 290, EntryDate: 1/31/2017 12:34:00 PM]}
Heights: {[Id: 1, Value: 5.7, EntryDate: 1/31/2017 12:34:00 PM]}
```

There are more list of vital signs in vital object which has similar structure and I need to filter on `EntryDate`.

I was trying to do this using linq, but didn't quite get it.

Comment: If the VitalXxx classes have similar structure, why do you even have multiple classes? You could just make a "generic" class and use it in different places. If you don't want to do this, an abstract base class would be nice i guess.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my comment, here is what i meant by using a "generic" vital-class:

```
public class GenericVital
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string EnterDate { get; set; }
}

public class Vital
{
  public double PaientId { get; set; }
  public List<GenericVital> Weights { get; set; }
  public List<GenericVital> Heights { get; set; }
}
```

(I know `GenericVital` is probably a bad name here. However, I think you get the point.)

You can then get the vitals with the date by:

```
var theDateYouAreLookingFor = DateTime.Now; // example date
var vitalsYouWant = vitals.Where(v => DateTime.Parse(v.EnterDate) == theDateYouAreLookingFor);
```

The problem is, that you can't distinguish if the vital is a Vital-Height or Vital-Weight. If you want to be able to tell the difference, you could add a property into the class which tells you what type this is (not recommended tho).

I think in the "better" solution would be to introduce an abstract base class like this:

```
public abstract class VitalBase
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
  public string EnterDate { get; set; }
}

public class VitalHeight : VitalBase
{
}

public class VitalWeight : VitalBase
{
}

public class Vital
{
  public double PaientId { get; set; }
  public List<VitalWeight> Weights { get; set; }
  public List<VitalHeight> Heights { get; set; }
}
```

You are able to filter your `List<VitalBase>` from `GetAllVitals()` similar as shown already and can get the type by reflection.

Another possibility would be the usage of `dynamic`. However, I think that would be overkill here.